# Retrieve contacts sorted by Modified date iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, addressbook, abaddressbook

How can I retrieve all address book contacts which are sorted according to their modified date? i.e. Contact with the latest modified date should come earlier in the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As there is no way to directly sort according to the modification date of ABPerson
here is something which I think works

```
- (NSArray *) getSortedContacts
{

    NSMutableArray * modificationDates = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
    if(addressBook != nil)
    {
        CFIndex nPeople = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount(addressBook);
        if(nPeople > 0)
        {
            CFArrayRef allPeople = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);
            for (int index = 0; index < nPeople; ++index)
            {
                ABRecordRef person = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(allPeople, index);
                NSNumber *contactID = [NSNumber numberWithInt:ABRecordGetRecordID(person)];
                NSDate *modificationDate = (NSDate*) ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonModificationDateProperty);
                [modificationDates addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:contactID,modificationDate, nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"contactID",@"modificationDate", nil]]];
            }
            if(allPeople)
                CFRelease(allPeople);
            allPeople = nil;
        }
    }
    [pool drain];

    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"modificationDate" ascending:TRUE];
    [modificationDates sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];

    return modificationDates;
}
```

when you get the sorted array, get the dictionary from the array and using the contactID and use it to get ABPerson object using this

```
ABRecordRef person = ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID(addressbook, (ABRecordID) [[dict valueForKey:@"contactID"] intValue]);
```

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

Use `kABPersonModificationDateProperty` property from ABPerson record.

```
CFDateRef modDate = ABRecordCopyValue(record, kABPersonModificationDateProperty);
```

gives you the modified date.

Comment: That's what I have already done. Question is how can I retrieve them in sorted order.

Comment: There is no direct sorting method available to return the ABPerson sorted by date. So, the way to do this is, get all the modified date and store it in an array as NSDate. Then sort the array of NSDate in an order and get the ABPerson accordingly.

Comment: Is there any way that my iOS app gets notified when some contact is modified?